# Adding quotes to 'link' command in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker

I've been using VS10 for a while for building a dll, but I want to demonstrate that it can be done in Eclipse as well.

The apparent symptom in Eclipse is that the linker fails with the irritating:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'
```

This is presumably because something is not protecting the spaces in the C:\Program Files(x86)... arguments, of which I have several.

I can get the command to run by copying it into a CMD prompt and manually putting quotes around the arguments that contain a space, so I'm 99.9% sure that the problem is Eclipse is not putting the quotes around these arguments.  The *working* command is:

```
link /DLL /debug /nologo /OUT:PIDExternalController.dll main.obj C:\Opt\Bladed\Main\Test\Code\ExternalController\Debug\ExternalControllerApi.lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\delayimp.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\Kernel32.Lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\oldnames.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\msvcrt.lib"
```

Eclipse's echo of the command is identical, but without the quotes (although this doesn't necessarily prove anything, as the compiler echo didn't show the quotes that it does in fact use).

I cannot find any options or legitimate mechanism to make Eclipse put quotes around its call to the linker - but this *must* be a common requirement.  Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: How did you port that program to Eclipse? Do you compile using a custom makefile?

Comment: I was starting from a clean start - part of the reason I am doing this is in order to document how a new user should go through the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Eclipse > Project > Properties > Paths and Symbols > Libraries tab, enclose the path to the library in single quotes:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\Kernel32.Lib'
```

There would be a warning that the path does not exist, but it should be gone after you rebuild your project.